# How to create a message in Azure Service Bus Queues after a new item is added to a Sharepoint 2013 list?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure, sharepoint-2013, azureservicebus

I need to create messages on a Windows Azure Service Bus Queue every time an item is created under a specific Sharepoint 2013 List. Later I would process those messages with another application.

Some guidance or examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about event receivers on your SP 2013 List?

something similar to the approach in the app sample mentioned here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/01/03/debugging-remote-event-receivers-with-visual-studio.aspx#service-bus